# Use JQuery in php file for read and parse the HTML XML

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to read and parse HTML file inside php code (on server side).
As much as I know, the easiest way to read html for choose nodes and nodes' childrens, is to use jQueries.
Can I include in php code jQueries for open an HTML file, read it, and return to the php code array object?
Thanks :-)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use javascript (jQuery) server side, because it is client side, Browser based.

The easiest way to read and parse HTML is [DOMDocument](http://uk.php.net/DOMDOcument), eg:

```
$html = new DOMDocument(); 
$html->loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.org'); 
$links = array(); 
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) { 
    $links[] = array('url' => $link->getAttribute('href'), 'text' => $link->nodeValue); 
} 
var_export($links);
```

Comment: Technically, you CAN use jquery server side. E.g. nodejs "jquery" module, but that jquery implementation is of course miles, miles apart from what someone like OP may think it is, and I would not recommend to use jquery module on server anyway especially for anyone who thinks that it is working the same way as client side jquery/javascript!

Comment: Technically you're right, I'm only trying to answer him for his sake, If I'll send him to `node.js` he will not understand a thing. Anyway .. good observation

Comment: Right you are, I would recommend OP stay very far from Node JS using the current mode of reasoning.

Comment: Thank all of you for your answers... I wanted to work with jQuery because I realy comfortable with it.

Comment: Maybe someone need to right librairy like jQuery for php, .NET, JAVA, etc., so it will be easy to read XML files... Other librairies, in compare to jQueries are nightmares...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, jQuery is JavaScript Library and runs in browser environment. So unless you got something like Node.js at your server side it will be hard or impossible to do it.

Comment: Yes, and that server side jQuery module is conceptually not the same thing as when you are using it client side. That jquery module is not identical even in the implementation to the way jquery works on the client side - they may as well be considered totally different! In fact, it's the same difference as between JS on the client and JS on the server - Node on the server is a JS interface to C modules! That 'Jquery" on the server is the same thing - interface to C-implemented modules, not actually Jquery!